# Error installing using_markers pkg

Tags: ros, catkin-make, ros-kinetic, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys, I am having installing packages around. Now I am following the tutorial *Markers: Sending Basic Shapes (C++)*. I have the *kinetic* version of ROS which I have installed using `apt-get` on Ubuntu 16.04.

The problem comes when I execute the command `catkin_make` in order to build my new code. I get the following error:

```
CMake Warning at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:76 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by
  "visualisation_msgs" with any of the following names:

    visualisation_msgsConfig.cmake
    visualisation_msgs-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "visualisation_msgs" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
  set "visualisation_msgs_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above
  files.  If "visualisation_msgs" provides a separate development package or
  SDK, be sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  using_markers/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)


-- Could not find the required component 'visualisation_msgs'. The following CMake error indicates that you either need to install the package with the same name or change your environment so that it can be found.
CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by
  "visualisation_msgs" with any of the following names:

    visualisation_msgsConfig.cmake
    visualisation_msgs-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "visualisation_msgs" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
  set "visualisation_msgs_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above
  files.  If "visualisation_msgs" provides a separate development package or
  SDK, be sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  using_markers/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/lucadg/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/lucadg/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Invoking "cmake" failed
```

---

Then I've tried to install the package **visualisation_msgs** as it is always available for kinetic and I still get the same error.

Thank you in advance for your help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243191/error-installing-using_markers-pkg/) by [lucadg](https://answers.ros.org/users/27866/lucadg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2016-09-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-09-06**:
Have you tried removing your `build` and `devel` folder and running `catkin_make` again? If it still fails, what is the output of `rospack find visualization_msgs`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Found it, the problem was a spelling mistake in the `CMakeLists.txt` of `using_markers` package.

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  visualisation_msgs
)
```

---

It should be:

```
 find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
 roscpp
 visualization_msgs
 )
```

Initially was `visualisation_msgs` but the package it is called `visualization-msgs`

---

Originally posted by [lucadg](https://answers.ros.org/users/27866/lucadg/) with karma: 63 on 2016-09-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0